# Change enabled to disabled and disabled to enable the bootstrap with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the input from disabled to enabled when clicks and returns from disabled to enabled when clicked

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tes" name="tes" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="submit" id="submit1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok success btn btn-primary btn" value=""> </button>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#submit1').click(function() {
      $('#tes').prop("disabled",true);
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-danger');
});
```

Comment: My answer is generalized and can be useful in full website anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one.

```js
$('#submit1').click(function() {
      $('#tes').prop("disabled",!$('#tes').prop("disabled"));
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-danger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tes" name="tes" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="submit" id="submit1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok success btn btn-primary btn" value="Submit">SUbmit </button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Vijay Maheriya, Your answer is also true and more simple

Answer (score 1):

> **Use this Generalized function in your project to make things enabled / disabled.**

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('#submit1').click(function() {
    $('#tes').toggleDisabled();
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-danger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tes" name="tes" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="submit" id="submit1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok success btn btn-primary btn" >Button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very nice as I expected ... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`.prop(property)` will return whether the property is set. You can use this to check the value and toggle it based on it's current value.

```
if( $('#tes').prop("disabled") )
    $('#tes').prop("disabled",false);
else
    $('#tes').prop("disabled",true);
```

You could reduce this to:

```
$('#tes').prop("disabled", !$('#tes').prop("disabled") )
```

This fetches the current value of the property, negates it with `!`, then sets that as the new value

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to toggle the  disable prop:

```
$('#submit1').click(function() {
      $('#tes').prop("disabled", !$('#tes').prop("disabled"));
});
```